# Flutter - unable to change textweight of an item from my items list

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I am trying to change the textweight to bold or normal depending on the object's item.boldTitle's value.

I am getting the following error. Item belongs to items list. I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Error: Invalid constant value

```
title: Text(
         item.name,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: item.boldTitle ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
          
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this way, remove the const keyword

```
title: Text(
  item.name,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: item.boldTitle ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
  ),
),
```